# Azure MongoDB Api Condition not supported

Tags: c#, mongodb, azure-cosmosdb

The following is my codes to remove documents:

```
    var filterAddInfo = builder.Lte("Claim_Date", branchEntity.Report_Date);
    mongoDB.BranchPerformance.FindOneAndUpdate(
     filterMain,
     Builders<BsonDocument>.Update.PullFilter("Add_Info", filterAddInfo));
```

It's working with MongoDB, but it's not working if I connect to Azure MongoDB Api. It prompt:

> Command findAndModify failed: Operator ''OPERATOR_PULL' with condition' is not supported..

Seems like condition (Eg. lte is not supported in Azure MongoDB Api). May I know is there any alternative way to change my codes cater for this condition?

Comment: CosmosDB is not MongoDB. It claims to have "limited" wire protocol support, but the actual translation is of course not supported for all operations. If you want "full" support for MongoDB operations, then you should be using MongoDB instead.

Comment: I have try to use some time that configuration on Azure but i figure out that is not a viable solution. I would strong suggest you to move to a custom distribution like "Bitnami" (try to search inside Azure Portal) or maybe your own virtual machine. Would be nice to hear someone else with a good experience about!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We do not yet support the pull operator with a condition specified. Please reach out to askcosmosmongoapi [at] microsoft [dot] com with a sample document, and we'll be happy to work with you on a workaround.

Comment: is there a plan to add support for this?